# Retrieve userprofiles by REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I'm trying to retrieve user people with rest api. But it does not work.

```
var getSpecificUserProperty = "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='"+encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|firstname.aftername@sitename.sharepoint.com')+"'";


 $.ajax({
  url: siteUrl + getSpecificUserProperty,
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: function(data, status){
    console.log(data.d.results);

 },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Why doesn't this code work? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you are missing `encodeURIComponent()`

URL should look like

> `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='"+encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|firstname.aftername@domain.se')+"'`

**PS:** After applying  `encodeURIComponent()` I got it working.

If you are using any REST client, then convert `i:0#.f|membership|firstname.aftername@domain.se` `into encodeURIComponent` at first.

Paste `encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|firstname.aftername@domain.se')` in any browser's console. It will output something like `"i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cfirstname.aftername%40domain.se"`. Finally using following end-point to get user profile properties

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cfirstname.aftername%40domain.se'
```

**Update#1**

- It should be `console.log(data.d);` not `console.log(data.d.results);`

Try following modified code

```
$.ajax({
  url: siteUrl+ "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='"+encodeURIComponent('i:0#.f|membership|firstname.aftername@sitename.sharepoint.com')+"'",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: function(data, status){
    console.log(data.d);

 },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: It is still empty, i dont recieve anything.

Comment: how did you try? can you update your question? @Jarule

Comment: I have updated my question now @Atish

Comment: What is the error now? @Jarule

Comment: Like before, i dont recieve any data

Comment: See my update now. you code has some error. @Jarule

Comment: It worked now, it was your new update that worked plus i used wrong domain. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See example from Microsoft site:
/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C**user**%40**domain**.onmicrosoft.com'"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx