# Retrieve users info with js and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, active-directory

I am facing following issue: I need to retrieve users from the whole domain not just siteusers list at sharepoint so that can can manipulate them and for example add them to sharepoint groups.

I have following script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loginName="domain\\username";
    getUserEmailByLoginName(loginName);
});
function getUserEmailByLoginName(loginName) {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Email&$filter=substringof('"+loginName+"',LoginName)";                  
    //execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                alert(data.d.results[0].Email); 
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

This one retrieves email from selected user. The problem is that if I enter users id who is not member of siteusers i dont retrieve anything. Is there a way how to lookup whole domain via javascript and then create user object out of it?

Thank you

Comment: Just SharePoint users, or anyone in the AD domain?

Comment: I would like to find info about anyone in the AD domain. Also people who have never been to sharepoint before.

Comment: Take a look at the Graph API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the wrong API call. You should instead use `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor`

See [Retrieve userprofiles by REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164300/retrieve-userprofiles-by-rest-api) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, with additional code i managed to achieve my goal.